# Property 'FileProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof content' : Nativescript with Angular on Android platform

Tags: android, angular2-nativescript, android-fileprovider

I try to open a file in my app on android platform. I use :

```
let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
let fileURI = android.net.Uri.fromFile(new java.io.File(file.path));
intent.setDataAndType(fileURI, "application/pdf");

let activity = android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, `Open Document with :`);
app.android.currentContext.startActivity(activity);
```

And it works for android version 7.1.1 and versions before. But on version 8.0. I have an error like that:

```
android.os.FileUriExposedException: file:///data/user/0/... exposed beyond app through Intent.getData()
```

So, I try to fix the problem with android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.

I modified my code to :

```
let intent = new android.content.Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.addFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
let context = application.android.currentContext;
let nativeFile = new java.io.File(file.path);
var uri = new android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"${applicationId}.provider,nativeFile",nativeFile);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
application.android.currentContext.startActivity(android.content.Intent.createChooser(intent, "Open File...");
```

And I modify the AndroidManifest.xml by adding this :

```
<provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
</provider>
```

I created a file named provider_paths.xml in the folder App_Ressources/Android/xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

I remove and add platform.
but i can't run the code because i still have an error :

```
Property 'FileProvider' does not exist on type 'typeof content'
```

[click here to see the the capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZTjg.png)

Comment: `I try to open a file in my app`. Is it? It looks more as if you try to let it be opened by another app.

Comment: `/data/user/0/...` That is an internal path. So you cannot use `<external-path ...`.

Comment: `context,"${applicationId}.provider` does not match `android:authorities="${applicationId}.fileprovider"`.

Comment: @greenapps i download the get the thanks to http.getFile() then, i want to see it (pdf).

Comment: @greenapps ok it's internal path, so what i should do ?

Comment: @greenapps ah yes but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Well change to `<internal-path..` ?

Comment: `remove and add platform` ???? `but i can't run the code because i still have an error`. Who gives that error? And when? The compiler or your app?

Comment: `in the folder App_Ressources/Android/xml :` ?? It should be in ...../res/xml.

Comment: without compile android.support.v4.content.FileProvider is not found.

Comment: @greenapps thank you, i put it in the right folder

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little late to the party, but for anyone else having this problem -

Add this to your AndroidManifest.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    ...
    <application
        ...
        <provider
            android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
        </provider>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Then create a `provider_paths.xml` file in `App_Resources/Android/xml` folder. Create the folder if it doesn't exist, then add the snippet below:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

One of the problems with the code in the OP's question is the use of **new** keyword on a static reference, and what appears to be an accidental copy/paste:

```
var uri = new android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,"${applicationId}.provider,nativeFile",nativeFile);
```

**What you actually want is:**

(In TypeScript)

```
const uri = android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, `${application.android.context.getPackageName()}.provider`, nativeFile);
```

The rest of the code is fine.

Hope this helps :)